# How to programmatically send voicemail message on the iPhone?

Tags: iphone, voicemail

Is there any way to send voicemail message from iphone application,I know from MessageUI framework it is not possible. I have search in google but could not find how to do this, I got only how to send text message, So any help much appreciated.

Comment: There is no any discussion over this question on above link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to send an audio file from message with current sdk....You can reach this requirement by upload that sound file to server and then send that url from message.