# copy video to uipasteboard

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uipasteboard

I have successfully able to copy or add the image to pasteboard by using following code:

```
if (ver_float < 6.0)
{
    UIPasteboard *pasteboard;
    pasteboard = [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard];
    NSString *filePath =pathToImage;
    [pasteboard setImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:filePath]];
}
else
{
    UIPasteboard *pasteboard = [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard];
    NSString *filePath =pathToImage;
    NSData *videoData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
    [pasteboard setData:videoData forPasteboardType:[UIPasteboardTypeListImage objectAtIndex:0]];

}

NSURL *urlstr = [NSURL URLWithString:@"sms:"];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:urlstr];
```

But the app which I am making is based on both images and videos so that user will be able to send image/video via imessage or messagecomposer. But as I have convert the image into data and added into pasteboard. It is working succesfully and sending through imessage. But I also need to send video via imessage. If anyone has any idea about this please provide me some suggestion or solution.

I would be very thankful for the help.

Comment: convert the video to data and use it like image. Did you tried this ?

Comment: Yes I try it but can't get the result...

Comment: hey here something new for me and really nice question..

Comment: Ya but i think it is not possible through pasteboard...

Comment: Hi @Vishal I'm also working on similar type. Did you find any solution about how to solve this ??

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have also faced the same issue in sending audio file from SMS.
But sending video and audio from SMS is not possible with current SDK.
You can do this by uploading that video to server and then send that uploaded URL.

[How to programmatically send voicemail message on the iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13645442/how-to-programmatically-send-voicemail-message-on-the-iphone/13645608#13645608)

Comment: Note that Enea's answer is correct and the accepted answer is *wrong*.  You can send video over SMS by copying to UIPasteboard as is asked in the original question.  Tested and verified to be working on iOS 8+.

Answer (score 9):

```
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://pathto.mp4"]];
UIPasteboard *pasteBoard = [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard];
[pasteBoard setData:data forPasteboardType:@"public.mpeg-4"];
```

`@"public.mpeg-4"` from http://www.escape.gr/manuals/qdrop/UTI.html

Comment: Hi @Enea, It was working good and I'm also do the same. But while converting to NSData and setData to pasteboard is really slow and taking some time. Do u have any idea how to boost it?

Answer (score 0):

In Swift to copy video to UIPasteboard, assuming you already have a data variable with the movie's binary do :

```
import UniformTypeIdentifiers 

UIPasteboard.general.setData(data ?? Data(),forPasteboardType: UTType.mpeg4Movie.description)
```

This worked for me. To test, I copied from the app and then pasted to the iPhone notes app.