# Swift NSPasteboard to copy an audio (.wav) file to clipboard

Tags: swift, audio, copy, nspasteboard

I've been pulling my hair out trying to find any resources on to do thi. It seems to be possible according to the documentation. But nothing I try works. I only need to copy the audio to the clipboard, the application I'm writing requires that the user manually switch to a different application to paste the audio in at specific locations. Copy & pasting text is easy of course, but audio I just cant seem to figure out. The files would be stored locally on the desktop/documents/etc.

Any help here would be greatly appreciated.

Running Swift 4 & 5

Comment: please provide your code with what you have tried so that we can get better idea about it

Comment: Check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13989625/copy-video-to-uipasteboard

Comment: Note that if your app has sandbox enabled you will need to present a NSSavePanel to allow the user to select the desktop as the destination